# How do I iterate all attributes of the nodes I extracted with sxd_xpath?

Tags: xpath, rust

I'm trying to iterate all the attributes of the nodes I extracted with sxd_xpath but I cannot figure out how

```
extern crate sxd_document;
extern crate sxd_xpath;

use std::fs;
use sxd_document::parser;
use sxd_xpath::{evaluate_xpath, Value};

fn main() {
    let content =
        fs::read_to_string("C:/afile.xml").expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
    let package = parser::parse(&content);
    match package {
        Ok(package) => {
            let document = package.as_document();
            let value = evaluate_xpath(&document, "//Node[@name=\"somenodename\"]")
                .expect("XPath evaluation failed");

            if let Value::Nodeset(nodes) = value {
                for node in nodes.document_order() {
                    //how to get all the attributes of all the nodes i'm parsing?
                }
            }
        }
        Err(err) => {
            println!("{:?}", err);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried reading the documentation but I cannot see a way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight-forward thing you can do is select the attributes directly in the XPath using `//Node[@name="somenodename"]/@*`:

```
let value = evaluate_xpath(&document, r#"//Node[@name="somenodename"]/@*"#)
    .expect("XPath evaluation failed");

if let Value::Nodeset(nodes) = value {
    for node in nodes.document_order() {
        if let Node::Attribute(attr) = node {
            println!("{}", attr.value());
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to iterate on the elements for whatever reason, you need to check if each node in the nodeset is an element, then get the attributes of the nodeset:

```
let value = evaluate_xpath(&document, r#"//Node[@name="somenodename"]"#)
    .expect("XPath evaluation failed");

if let Value::Nodeset(nodes) = value {
    for node in nodes.document_order() {
        if let Node::Element(elem) = node {
            for attr in elem.attributes() {
                println!("{}", attr.value());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make use of Rust's iterator chaining and some conversion methods on `Node`:

```
let value = evaluate_xpath(&document, r#"//Node[@name="somenodename"]"#)
    .expect("XPath evaluation failed");

if let Value::Nodeset(nodes) = value {
    for attr in nodes
        .document_order()
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|n| n.element())
        .flat_map(|e| e.attributes())
    {
        println!("{}", attr.value());
    }
}
```

Complete setup:

```
use sxd_document::parser; // 0.3.2
use sxd_xpath::{evaluate_xpath, Value}; // 0.4.2

fn main() {
    let content = r#"<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <foo>
      <Node name="somenodename" id="1" />
      <bar>
        <Node name="somenodename" id="2" />
      </bar>
    </foo>
    "#;

    let package = parser::parse(&content).expect("unable to parse");
    let document = package.as_document();

    // Various methods here
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the primary author of SXD-Document and SXD-XPath.